# Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN Laptop function key is not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, samsung, function-keys

I have a Samsung NP355V5C-S03IN laptop.

When using the function key to control volume, it is stuck. The wireless key is not working either.

Please advise me on a good driver for my motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it isn't solved

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install samsung-tools 

sudo reboot
```

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/app/samsung-tools/

Comment: Could you provide some explanation as to what these PPAs are and why they might solve the problem?